# UnityEngine.JsonUtility serialise enumeration items to name rather than item value (int)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

Using Unity's JsonUtility is is there a way to serialise an enumeration item to its string name rather than its integer value?

Apparently this can be achieved with JSON.NET `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`, but I'd rather not have to use that if possible.

Why I need this is **beyond the scope of this question**, but it's to do with old serialised files still working when the enumeration has changed since it was generated and avoiding having to administer that manually etc.

Thanks.

Comment: While I know it's outside of the scope of the question, I feel I should add that JsonUtility is a pretty poor tool in general, and after attempting to use it for a few days I moved over to a 3rd party solution. Best of luck figuring it out!

Comment: @lase Yeah I'm aware of it's limitations. It's recent slight upgrade to now work with List<T> gives me 95% of the functionality I needs so I was willing to give it one last go. It looks like JSON.NET is the only route really.